# pyglet - Why does the player not return to the command line?

Tags: python-2.7, pyglet

I implemented a basic script to play a song using pyglet. However, I get an error and the control does not return to the Command Line and I have to Ctrl+C out of it. What might be happening here?

My code is :

```
import pyglet
song = pyglet.resource.media('g.wav', streaming = False)
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()
pyglet.app.exit()
```

I simply get the following :

```
AL lib: pulseaudio.c:331: PulseAudio returned minreq > tlength/2; expect break up
OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.
```

And the control does not return.

However, when I add :

```
win = pyglet.window.Window()
```

Then I get a Window that I can close and then the playback stops.

Can someone tell me how I can implement a piece of code here that plays the file when I run and after playing, returns the command back to the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to play the sound and go back to the command line.

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('sound.wav')
music.play()

def exit_callback(dt):
    pyglet.app.exit()

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(exit_callback , music.duration)
pyglet.app.run()
```

For more information about how this works you can read this other question:
[Pyglet sound playing on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774681/pyglet-sound-playing-on-python)